# I want to make the animation bigger when I click the pie in ApexCharts

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I want to make the animation bigger when I click the pie in ApexCharts.

I looked it up on the Internet, but I couldn't find a solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmadI.png)
It gets bigger when I click it, is there any way to get bigger?

Comment: Can you share your code, so that i try scale css property on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `transform: scale(x, y);` to make your div bigger and you can add a transition if you want to add duration in this transformation. in order to make it big you need to add your transform as a class to your element.